# PHP MySQL array error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, web

I am having trouble with a function for a PHP/MySQL instant messaging system.  A variable ($sql) is defined as a MySQL query, which is then queried, and returns a resource ID.  However, the following while statement returns 'Array' instead of its supposed contents.

```
    <?php

// Fetches a summary of the conversations.
function fetch_conversation_summary(){
        $sql = "SELECT
                                `conversations`.`conversation_id`,
                                `conversations`.`conversation_subject`,
                                MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `conversation_last_reply`,
                                MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `conversation_unread`
                        FROM `conversations`
                        LEFT JOIN `conversations_messages` ON  `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
                        INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
                        WHERE `conversations_members`.`user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                        AND `conversations_members`.`conversation_deleted` = 0
                        GROUP BY `conversations`.`conversation_id`
                        ORDER BY `conversation_last_reply` DESC";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $conversations = array();

        while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
                $conversations[] = array(
                        'id'                            => $row['conversation_id'],
                        'subject'                       => $row['conversation_subject'],
                        'last_reply'            => $row['conversation_last_reply'],
                        'unread_messages'       => ($row['conversation_unread'] == 1),
                );
        }

        return $conversations;
}

// Fetches all of the messages in the given converstion.
function fetch_conversation_messages($conversation_id){
        $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

    $sql = "SELECT
                            `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
                            `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `message_unread`,
                            `conversations_messages`.`message_text`,
                            `users`.`user_name`
                    FROM `conversations_messages`
                    INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
                    INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
                    WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                    AND `conversations_members`.`user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                    ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $result;
    $messages = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
            $messages[] = array(
                    'date'          => $row['message_date'],
                    'unread'        => $row['message_unread'],
                    'text'          => $row['message_text'],
                    'user_name'     => $row['user_name'],
            );
    }
    var_dump( $messages );
        }


// Sets the last view time to the current time for the given conversation.
function update_conversation_last_view($conversation_id){
        $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;
        $time = time() + 18000;
        $sql ="UPDATE `conversations_members`
                        SET `conversation_last_view` = {$time}
                        WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                        AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";

        mysql_query($sql);     
}

 // Creates a new conversation, making the given users a member.
function create_conversation($user_ids, $subject, $body){
        $subject        = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($subject));
        $body           = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($body));

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `conversations` (`conversation_subject`) VALUES ('{$subject}')");

        $conversation_id = mysql_insert_id();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_messages` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`, `message_date`, `message_text`)
                        VALUES ({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '{$body}')";

        mysql_query($sql);

        $values = array("({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)");

        foreach ($user_ids as $user_id){
                $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $values = array("({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)");            }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_members` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`, `conversation_last_view`, `conversation_deleted`)
                        VALUES " . implode(", ", $values);

                        mysql_query($sql);
}


// Checks to see if the given user is a member of the given conversation.
   function validate_conversation_id($conversation_id){
   $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM `conversations_members`
   WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
   AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
   AND `conversation_deleted` = 0";

   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   return(mysql_result($result, 0) == 1);
   }
    // Adds a message to the given conversation.
    function add_conversation_message($conversation_id, $text){
            $conversation_id        = (int)$conversation_id;
                $text                   = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($text));

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_messages` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`, `message_date`, `message_text`)
                        VALUES ({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '{$text}')";

        mysql_query($sql);

        mysql_query("UPDATE `conversations_members` SET `conversation_deleted` = 0 where `conversation_id = {$conversation_id}");
}

// Deletes (or marks as deleted) a given conversation.
function delete_conversation($conversation_id){
        $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `conversation_deleted`
                        FROM `conversations_members`
                        WHERE `user_id` != {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                        AND `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        //if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 && mysql_result($result, 0) == 1){
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations_members` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations_messages` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
        }else{
                $sql = "UPDATE `conversations_members`
                                SET `conversation_deleted` = 1
                                WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                                AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";

                mysql_query($sql);

        }
}
?>
```

I have tried echoing the error, $messages (as you can see from the code).  In addition, I have echoed the result of the SQL query.

Update: I did the mentioned var_dump and my result was:
Resource id #16array(0) { } Array ( )

Comment: What error message do you see?

Comment: There are no error messages, however 'echo $messages' just gives me 'array' and I get 'resource id #16' when I echo $result

Comment: @user3308065 This is absolutely normal.

Comment: How do I then fix this error

Comment: sorry, not error, but 'array' so that instead I can view the details queried

Comment: You can't `echo` an array. Use `print_r` instead...

Comment: @user3308065 Please state CLEARLY, what you exactly need as a result!

Comment: Something like this - Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 1322254667 [text] => one [user_name] => bob ) )

Comment: Like I said, make sure your query does return any rows. For example you can do this by "echo mysql_num_rows($result);"

Comment: Nothing is returned; I understand that this is the problem, however I do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 4):

Sure it prints Array because that is what $messages is. If you want to print the contents of $messages you can use [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var-dump) or [print_r](http://www.php.net/print-r).

Similar reason for $result. $result is a resource type (at least as long as the query is successful). Printing it does not make sense since it is an internal reference. You have to pass it to a function like [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) or [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) or similar that can process such a resource.

---

Regarding your updated question: This output tells you that your array is empty and does not contain any elements. Are you sure your SQL-Query returns any rows?

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: @user3308065 He gave you two links, I assure you those have enough examples.

Comment: sorry - I am a big noob when it comes to PHP and MySQL

Comment: You need to do like `echo( $messages[0]['text'] );` to see the first message returned by MySQL.

Comment: I've tried these things but to no avail

Comment: replace in your code `echo $messages;` with `var_dump( $messages );` and edit your question showing the output.

Comment: I have changed the question as requested

Comment: Check that your query returns any rows